# Proving an inequality for a recursive function using induction

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations

Recently, I have been studying induction proofs as preparation for an exam and I've been stuck at the following exercise for quite some time now, even though I feel like I'm almost there.

Let $T(n)$ be defined as follows

$$
\begin{equation}
T(n) \leq 
\begin{cases}
2 & 1 \leq n \leq 3 \\
3T(\frac{n}{4}) + n\sqrt{n} & n \geq 4
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$

Prove by induction that $T(n) \leq n^{\frac{3}{2}}*\log_4(n) + 2n$.

After looking at the base cases, when $1 \leq n \leq 3$, I tried to do the induction step. Assuming that $T(n) \leq n^{\frac{3}{2}}*\log_4(n) + 2n$ holds for all $n$ up to and including some $k$, then I would need to show

$$
T(k) \leq k^{\frac{3}{2}}*\log_4(k) + 2k \implies T(k+1) \leq (k+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}*\log_4(k+1) + 2(k+1)
$$

So far I have got the following after using the function definition and inserting the induction hypothesis

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
T(k+1) & \leq 3T(\frac{k+1}{4}) + (k+1)\sqrt{k+1} \\
       & \leq 3((\frac{k+1}{4})^{\frac{3}{2}} * \log_4(\frac{k+1}{4}) + 2 * \frac{k+1}{4}) + (k+1)^{\frac{3}{2}} \\
       & = 3((\frac{k+1}{4})^{\frac{3}{2}} * (\log_4(k+1) - 1) + \frac{k+1}{2}) + (k+1)^{\frac{3}{2}} \\
       & = 3((\frac{k+1}{4})^{\frac{3}{2}} * \log_4(k+1) - (\frac{k+1}{4})^{\frac{3}{2}} + \frac{k+1}{2}) + (k+1)^{\frac{3}{2}} \\
       & = \frac{3}{8}*(k+1)^{\frac{3}{2}} * \log_4(k+1) - \frac{3}{8}*(k+1)^{\frac{3}{2}} + \frac{3}{2} * (k+1) + (k+1)^{\frac{3}{2}} \\
       & = \frac{3}{8}*(k+1)^{\frac{3}{2}} * \log_4(k+1) + \frac{5}{8}*(k+1)^{\frac{3}{2}} + \frac{3}{2} * (k+1)
\end{split}
\end{equation} 
$$

I know that I'm now very close to finishing the proof, but that middle $\frac{5}{8}*(k+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}$ term is making me scratch my head. If it weren't there the proof would be easily finished, but I don't know how to get rid of that middle term so that I can show that $T(k+1) \leq (k+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}*\log_4(k+1) + 2(k+1)$. Some hint or help would be much appreciated here.

Comment: Combine that middle term with the previous term

Comment: @YuvalPeres That would result in $\frac{1}{8} * (k+1)^{\frac{3}{2}} * (3 * \log_4(k+1) + 5) + \frac{3}{2} * (k+1)$. How would I continue from there though?

Comment: @YuvalPeres Thank you I have found a solution now with your hint. Now that you have pointed that out it became very obvious. Thanks again.